# Create progress bar for R functions

Tags: r

I have a long waiting function like this `myList <- lapply(X=input,rjson::fromJSON)`.
Is it possible to create visible progress bar for this function(R-studio)?
THX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
myList <- plyr::llply(input,rjson::fromJSON,.progress="text")
```

`llply` is the `plyr` analogue of `lapply` (it takes a list as input and returns a list); you can return different output types via `ldply` or `laply` ...

From `?plyr::create_progress_bar`:

> There are currently four types of progress bar: "none", "text",
>        "tk", and "win".  See the individual documentation for more
>        details.  In plyr functions, these can either be specified by
>        name, or you can create the progress bar object yourself if you
>        want more control over its appe[a]rance. See the examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either:

- the [progress](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progress/index.html) package and the `progress_bar()` function
- the `setTxtProgressBar()` built-in function

Examples are informative in the two functions helpfiles.

Comment: and if it's long enough for you to start something else but still want to be beeped back, [beepr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beepr/index.html) is the best option I have found so far.